# In OnPaint() event, how to check if a given rectangle intersects with the invalidated region?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, rectangles, region

In Winforms, it's possible to create a region that is not a rectangle and invalidate it this way :

```
Region region = new Region(new Rectangle(...));
region.Union(new Rectangle(...));                   
Invalidate(region);
```

Then, in `OnPaint()` event, only the region invalidated above will be drawn again:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{   
    //will only repaint the region invalidated above
    //even if ClipRectangle area is bigger than that
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, e.ClipRectangle); 
}
```

Inside `OnPaint()` event, is there a way to check if a given rectangle intersect with the invalidated area ?

I could use `rectangle.Intersect(e.ClipRectangle)` but this might gave false positives.

EDIT : it seems what I want is possible using the [GetUpdateRgn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getupdatergn) Win32 function (AFAIK there is no direct Winforms equivalent of that function)

Comment: After reading the page on Control.Invalidate and Control.Paint Event, it's not clear to me that only the region specified in Invalidate is actually repainted.
It seems possible that after calling Invalidate multiple times, a rectangle is repainted that includes all specified regions. This would explain why the PaintEventArgs contains a rectangle and not a more generic region.
Do you have more insight into this?

Comment: Painting with a random color in OnPaint() clearly show that only invalidated region is repainted (and not what is specified in FillRectangle or other draw functions parameters).

Comment: I see, that's interesting.
In that case, you probably have to keep track of all the rectangles you invalidated. If they are set when the Paint event is raised, you have to check intersection with all these rectangles individually. If any intersects, you redraw your graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question :

It's possible to get the update region by calling `GetUpdateRgn()` function in WM_PAINT event, before `BeginPaint()` is called.
To know if a rectangle is inside region, `IsVisible()` method is used. This is a GDI api call (unlike `Rectangle.Intersect()`) and so it's usually just as slow as calling a GDI drawing function directly (eg: `DrawText()`) and let GDI do the discard job if necessary.

```
private Region region;    
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
{   
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            region = null;
            IntPtr hrgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
            try
            {
                int result = GetUpdateRgn(Handle, hrgn, false);
                if (result == SIMPLEREGION || region == COMPLEXREGION)
                {
                    region = Region.FromHrgn(hrgn); 
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                DeleteObject(hrgn);
            }
            break;                
    } 
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{       
    var rectangle = ...
    if (region != null && region.IsVisible(rectangle))
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Here is the native win32 functions declarations :

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr CreateRectRgn(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetUpdateRgn(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hRgn, bool bErase);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

const int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;
const int SIMPLEREGION = 2;
const int COMPLEXREGION = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Rectangle> rectangleList;
```

When you invalidate, you set your rectangleList:

```
rectangleList = getRectangles(...);
Region region = new Region(new Rectangle(...));
foreach(Rectangle rect in rectangleList)
{
    region.Union(rect);  
}                 
Invalidate(region);
```

And in the paint method, you check if any Rectangles in your rectangleList intersect, then you clear it:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{   
    bool intersection = false;
    foreach(Rectangle rect in rectangleList)
    {
        if(e.ClipRectangle.Intersect(rect) 
        {
            intersection = true;
            break;
        }
    } 

    if(intersection)
    {
        rectangleList.Clear();
        DoIntersectionStuff();
    }
    else
    {
        DoNonIntersectionStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if Windows send a WM_PAINT message to the Winforms app ? Some area are not going to be painted because rectangleList will be empty.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in case of intersection, and what if it doesn't intersect?

Comment: I want to avoid/skip some uneeded calls to DrawText() (ClipRectangle is quite large but only a few areas need to be repainted)

Comment: In what case? I believe I gave you a good idea how to determine if your specific invalidated area intersects the redrawn rectangle, so I believe I answered the question.

What you do after determining if the areas intersect or not, is outside the scope of the question. I adjusted the code accordingly.